# Is there any Netbeans palette for primefaces

Tags: java, jsp, primefaces

Are there any netbeans palette available for fast drag & drop development ? The same as JavaFX has a visual layout tool (Scene-Builder) for fast components drag & drop.

Comment: Nope. NB Dropped visual component support since NB 6.7.1. and Visual Web Pack

Comment: And what about Eclipse, does it has visual component support with PrimeFaces or ADF Faces.